# Adding touchstart event listener causes delay with click event listener in Chrome on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, dom-events, touch-event

I noticed that adding a `touchstart` event listener to buttons seems to cause a delay with the `click` event listener when running in Chrome on my iPhone X test device (I tested with Chrome v108.0.5359.52 and v110.0.5481.83). I haven't been able to reproduce the issue in Firefox or Safari on the same device, or in any browser on my Android device. When running the example HTML below in Chrome on an iOS device, try cycling through pressing each button in the top row, and you should get an acceptable level of responsiveness (the result div's content should update to match the pressed button reliably). However, the bottom row of buttons responds very poorly to button presses (the result div's content does not always update to match the pressed button). If you cycle through the bottom row of buttons slowly then it will work better, but why is there a difference in performance between the top row of buttons and the bottom row of buttons, and only in Chrome on iOS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Buttons</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, minimal-ui=1">
        <style>
            .buttonHolder {
                margin-top: 50px;
            }
            .result {
                text-align: center;
                margin: 25px 0;
                font-size: 36px;
            }
            .button {
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 3px solid black;
                border-radius: 8px;
                padding: 25px 0;
                margin: 0 1px;
                text-align: center;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                width: calc(25% - 2px);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            main();

            function main() {
                const output = document.createElement('div');
                output.append(makeButtonsV1());
                output.append(makeButtonsV2());
                document.body.append(output);
            }

            function makeButtonsV1() {
                const buttonHolder = document.createElement('div');
                buttonHolder.classList.add('buttonHolder');
                const result = document.createElement('div');
                result.classList.add('result');
                buttonHolder.append(result);
                const buttonLabels = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR'];
                result.textContent = buttonLabels[0];
                for (const label of buttonLabels) {
                    const button = document.createElement('button');
                    button.classList.add('button');
                    button.textContent = label;
                    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        result.textContent = label;
                    });
                    buttonHolder.append(button);
                }
                return buttonHolder;
            }

            function makeButtonsV2() {
                const buttonHolder = document.createElement('div');
                buttonHolder.classList.add('buttonHolder');
                const result = document.createElement('div');
                result.classList.add('result');
                buttonHolder.append(result);
                const buttonLabels = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR'];
                result.textContent = buttonLabels[0];
                for (const label of buttonLabels) {
                    const button = document.createElement('button');
                    button.classList.add('button');
                    button.textContent = label;
                    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        result.textContent = label;
                    });
                    // Adding this seems to cause a delay with the above click handler
                    // when testing in Chrome on iOS (not reproducible in other
                    // browsers on iOS or any browser on my Android device, etc.).
                    button.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {});
                    buttonHolder.append(button);
                }
                return buttonHolder;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```